# ROS RGBD SLAM Problem

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, rgbd-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I am using ubuntu 11.10 with ROS electric and Kinect.

when i run the application, it works fine in pause state. Upon processing, it results in exit with following message.

bool g2o::HyperGraphActionLibrary::registerAction(g2o::HyperGraphElementAction*): creating collection for "writeGnuplot"
bool g2o::HyperGraphActionLibrary::registerAction(g2o::HyperGraphElementAction*): creating collection for "draw"

(rgbdslam:2800): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(rgbdslam:2800): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(rgbdslam:2800): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(rgbdslam:2800): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[rgbdslam-1] process has died [pid 2800, exit code -11].
log files: /home/vision-lab/.ros/log/fb3c4690-d763-11e1-aad7-f80f4113f0b0/rgbdslam-1*.log
all processes on machine have died, roslaunch will exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done

Please tell what is missing and why I am getting this reply.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39941/ros-rgbd-slam-problem/) by [Tahir](https://answers.ros.org/users/2927/tahir/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-07-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tahir](https://answers.ros.org/users/2927/tahir/) on 2012-07-26**:
It works good with roslaunch rgbdslam kinect+rgbdslam.launch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The only relevant information is this:

```
[rgbdslam-1] process has died [pid 2800, exit code -11]. log files: /home/vision-lab/.ros/log/fb3c4690-d763-11e1-aad7-f80f4113f0b0/rgbdslam-1.log
```

Signal 11 roughly means that a memory segment is accessed that doesn't belong to the process. You probably need to run it in a debugger to get to the source of this error.

How do you start it? A standard launch file? A custom one?

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2012-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-pixbuf

hope this helps...:)

---

Originally posted by [Yum.my](https://answers.ros.org/users/2780/yum.my/) with karma: 11 on 2012-07-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1